# how can I use the copy method for case classes on a list of that case class?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, case-class

I have a list of records (record is a case class). I am trying to simultaneously update all of the records in the list (using the copy function) and return a list of the updated records.
I tried to use a foreach method but it's not allowing me to produce the list as a result.

This is what I tried so far, I'm not sure if any of this is right

```
def update_record(record: List[Rec]): List[Rec] = {
  val result = record.foreach(r => {
    r.copy(firstname = get_firstname(r, record), lastname = get_lastname(r, record))
  })
  result
}
```

but result doesn't produce a list so I'm not sure what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `map` instead of `foreach`.

```
def update_record(record: List[Rec]: List[Rec] =
  record.map { r =>
    r.copy(firstname = get_firstname(r, record), lastname = get_lastname(r, record))
  }
```

Anyways, it would be good to follow some tutorial or course or read a book about the language. This is just basic knowledge of the standard library.

Some links that may be useful:

- [**Scala tour**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html).
- [**Scala book**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/introduction.html).
- [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/).
- [**Scala style guide**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/).